# UWP WACK Test always fails with the HighVersionLie issue

Tags: uwp, windows-dev-center, wack

Using **Visual Studio 2019 16.8.1**, I've created a UWP package but can't get the WACK test to succeed due to one error. Here's the process I got about:

**My Min and Target versions:**

[image]

**My process in Visual Studio to create the package:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**I don't remember ever using specific code related to OS versioning, but yet I always fail the Platform Version Launch test:**

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using the local WACK tool? If it is, you could try to upload your package to the store directly, There will be an online WACK test when your app is submitted. We will take that result as standard.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was simply to have it validated through the UWP publishing process online instead of the local WACK test app.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround to enable running WACK locally in the meantime:
https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/6331#issuecomment-738684154